# Vector.indexOf won't work for my class

Tags: java

I'm building simple phonebook. Thus a have created a class "Person":

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
String Name;
String number;

public Person(String name,String Num) {
    Name=name;
    number=Num;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Person another) {
    return Name.compareTo(another.getName());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return Name;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(!(obj instanceof Person) && !(obj instanceof String))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(obj instanceof Person)
            return Name.toLowerCase().equals(((Person)obj).getName().toLowerCase());
        else
            return Name.toLowerCase().equals(((String)obj).toLowerCase());
    }

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Name.hashCode();
} }
```

In some other part of the program i'm creating a Vector, populate it with "Person" objects but when i try to search a person BY NAME using `vctPerson.indexOf("John")` I always get -1 as result (not found). What's wrong with my code? I have implemented custom "equals" that should work with strings, and according to docs, "indexOf" is using "equals" to compare objects...

EDIT: I KNOW, I SHOULD SEARCH AFTER PHONE NUMBER, NOT NAME BUT IT's IRRELEVANT FOR THIS EXAMPLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `Vector` does in `indexOf`:

```
if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
```

where `o` would be `"John"`. So you would have to override `Sting.equals` to do the right comparison (just kidding). Or you could use

```
vector.indexOf(new Person("John", null));
```

which will call your `equals`. Strictly speaking that will solve your question.

But in the long run you should not use `Vector` for that, because every `indexOf` call will iterate through the list - this is not very efficient.

A better way is a `Map` like `HashMap` where you can store key-value pairs. Lookup using the key is much cheaper than `Vector.indexOf` if here are a couple of entries.

```
Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<String, Person>();
Person p = new Person("John", "1234");
map.put(p.getName().toLowerCase(), p);

// loopup
Person john = map.get("John".toLowerCase());
```

Comment: But what if i want to sort my phone book by name or phone number? :)

Comment: Then two `SortedMap`s will be even better: The first one hold all (Name, Person) pairs, the second holds (Number, Person) pairs. That way you can always search with both keys and you can print lists using either sorting method without having to sort by hand. A suitable implementation for `SortedMap` is `TreeMap`. Each `TreeMap` requires a `Comparator` which will decide the sorting order.

Answer (score 2):

you called `vctPerson.indexOf("John")` . In this case, `Vector` call `"John".equals( vctPerson.get( indexValue )` . As equals of `String` is called, String's equals compare "John" and `Person` object.

But as String's `equals()` does not return true when target object is not an instance of String, `"John".equals( vctPerson.get( indexValue )` always return false. So result is always -1.

So, you can't use `vctPerson.indexOf("John")`. If you want to use vector, you need to traverse vector manually.

Answer (score 1):

Your equals is broken: You objects may equal to a `String` (and that's what you're trying to exploit), but no `String` may ever equal to you object. Breaking symmetry of `equals` breaks everything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be on the safe side you can always use 
1) `Map<String,Person>` to make the relation between a person and his name 
2) Make your own class that extends java.util.Vector and overrides its indexOf method 
3) place a breakpoint in your equals method and see what's going on when indexOf gets called. 
Whatever's going on, though, it's better that you don't rely on the current implementation of indexOf that's specified in the JDK documentation since it may get changed upon the release of a next version of the JDK :)